# Similarity of Equations used in Physics and Economics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, econo-physics

I just read that there was a machine to simulate economic processes using the flow of water (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MONIAC) since *some equations in economics are similar to the equations in fluid mechanics*.

1. What are these equations or the concepts shared?
2. Are there other equations that share the similarity in both sciences?

Comment: I heard, brownian motion is used in financial markets. As I am not an economist, I leave the rest for your research (unless some good soul includes it in the answer).

Comment: The link you provided says "hydraulic macro-economics" is used to model Keynesian systems, so the answer is a manifest "no".

Comment: @Umaxo well, Black-Scholes is a diffusion equation.

Comment: Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution is usually used in recent papers, to show why economic inequality is inevitable. https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn22105-inequality-the-physics-of-our-finances/#:~:text=More%20than%20100%20years%20ago,called%20the%20Maxwell-Boltzmann%20distribution.&text=The%20result%20was%20a%20wealth,of%20the%20Maxwell-Boltzmann%20distribution.

Comment: Thanks, i started reading about brownian motion and Boltzmann distribution, the Black-Sholes will be the next. I think this paper will be useful:  Mechanical Models in Economic Dynamics. doi:10.2307/2549721.